# Как понять что TableView скролится

Tags: ios, swift, прокрутка, uitableview

У меня есть на экране хедер в виде UIImageView и TableView. Мне нужно при скроле TableView менять изображение в UIImageView

Comment: Нужно подписаться на делегат UIScrollViewDelegate.

Answer (score 3):

Так-как `UITableView` наследуется от `UIScrollView`, можно использовать его методы делегата.

Метод `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` работает во время скрола таблицы.
Тут можно достать `offset` если вас интересует на сколько вы проскролили вашу таблицу `tableView.contentOffset`

Так-же можно использовать метод `func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)`. 
Он отрабатывает когда вы закончили скролить таблицу.